# How do I render current day in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am pulling some data from a REST API in my app and I am trying to parse the current day into the results using​ moment.

Here is an example of my code:

```
{restaurants.map((item, index) =>
<View key={item.id}>
<Text>
{`item.store_open_close.time.${currentDay.toLowerCase()}.opening_time`}</Text></View>
)}
```

but this is rendering, e.g.:
item.store_open_close.time.thursday.opening_time

and not what I expected, e.g.:

10:00 am

I feel like I'm almost there? any help appreciated. Thanks!

PS - My data for restaurants looks like this

```
"store_open_close": {
        "enabled": true,
        "time": {
            "sunday": {
                "status": "close",
                "opening_time": "",
                "closing_time": ""
            },
            "monday": {
                "status": "open",
                "opening_time": "10:00 am",
                "closing_time": "7:00 pm"
            },
            "tuesday": {
                "status": "open",
                "opening_time": "10:00 am",
                "closing_time": "7:00 pm"
            },
            "wednesday": {
                "status": "open",
                "opening_time": "10:00 am",
                "closing_time": "7:00 pm"
            },
            "thursday": {
                "status": "open",
                "opening_time": "10:00 am",
                "closing_time": "7:00 pm"
            },
            "friday": {
                "status": "open",
                "opening_time": "10:00 am",
                "closing_time": "7:00 pm"
            },
            "saturday": {
                "status": "open",
                "opening_time": "10:00 am",
                "closing_time": "7:00 pm"
            }
        },
        "open_notice": "We are open",
        "close_notice": "Sorry we are closed"
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
<Text>{item.store_open_close.time[currentDay.toLowerCase()].opening_time}</Text>
```

Previously you were using a [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and only expressing `${currentDay.toLowerCase()}` in js, but you wanted the full line.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. This worked like a charm. I can't upvote your answer as my rep is not high enough, but I will be sure to do so when I can and suggest others do so also. Thanks!!

Comment: kind of.. was it I needed to parse the data as an object and not a string? (I'm new to JS and react) - thanks for your follow up.

Comment: You use the string literals to have a string and js expression together so instead of doing `return 'hello' + name;` , you can do `return ´hello ${name}´ ;` - Note these should be backticks `´ ` in this comment